# Angular2: Promise return

Tags: javascript, service, angular, promise

I want to get the comments from my API.
So, the function should promise a return?
What is better? Clasic or promise return?

And I have still a problem, the promise return return undefined.

**comments.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommentService } from '../services/comment.service';
import { Comment } from '../class/Comment';

@Component({
  template: 'dadada',
  providers: [CommentService]
})

export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {
    coms: Comment[];

    constructor(private commentService: CommentService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() { 
        console.log( this.commentService.testfunction() ); 

        this.commentService.get_all_comments().then((data) => {
            this.coms = data;
          });
        console.log ( this.commentService.get_all_comments2() );
        console.log ( this.coms );
    }
}
```

**comment.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Comment, Comments } from '../class/Comment';

@Injectable()
export class CommentService {
    testfunction() {
        return 'valoare';
    }
    get_all_comments() {
        return Promise.resolve(Comments);
    }
    get_all_comments2() {
        return Comments;
    }    
}
```

**Comment.ts**

```
export class Comment {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  author: string;
  created_at: number;
  updated_at: number;
}

export const Comments: Comment[] = [
  {id: 1, text: 'Look I am a test comment.', author: 'Chris Sevilleja', created_at: 0, updated_at: 0}
];
```

And I get in console these:

> valoare
>
> Array [ Object ]
>
> undefined

Comment: Is the question really if it is better to return a promise or a plain value? You use a promise only if you need to make an async call (where you can't return a plain value), otherwise sync execution is always preferred, except when you explicitly want to execute something async for whatever reason.

Comment: I seen on Angular site this example.. I just asked, you know why doesn't work? I did like on angular site..

Comment: On the Angular site they simulate an async call for demonstration purposes about how to cope with async execution. This doesn't mean it is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code inside the `then(...)` (same for observables with `subscribe(...)`

```
ngOnInit() { 
    console.log( this.commentService.testfunction() ); 

    this.commentService.get_all_comments().then((data) => {
        this.coms = data;
        console.log ( this.commentService.get_all_comments2() );
        console.log ( this.coms );
      });
}
```

The purpose of `Promise` and `then(...)` is to enable to chain calls so that a subsequent call is executed when the previous one completes.

Async execution means that the call is enqueued into the event queue and sync code (your `console.log()`) is executed next. The code passed to `.then(...)` is eventually executed when the `Promise` resolves (usually when the response from the server arrives).